# Glassfish 5 not working with Intellij 2017 2.4

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I am new to Intellij ide and i'm having issues running Glassfish 5 or any previous version on Intellij 2017 2.4.

After selecting `New Project > Java Enterprise > Web Application` i had to specify the application server, to which i selected the folder of glassfish 5, jdk is set to 1.8 and java ee to 7. So far so good, no errors and the project gets created. Then i have a greyed "play" icon next to GlassFish 5.0.0 in the upper right of the corner that says that i have to configure it, i click `Edit Configurations` and the Run/Debug Configurations opens up [image]
Everything seems fine and when i click the "play" green button to start the server and run the project i have **projectName:war exploded** under Deployment and

```
[2017-09-26 08:47:57,836] Artifact testfornew:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
```

Under output. Coming from Netbeans setting glassfish up was pretty straightforward, i've checked a couple of solutions online including [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-web-application-deployment.html) but they don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same problem and [I found that it is caused by an issue with the JDK software](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7688/gipqi/index.html). So the NullPointerException thrown at AsadminMain.java:57 can be solved by **checking your system variables** (**PATH**, JAVA_HOME). Be sure that they reference to an acceptable JDK supported by your GlassFish version. GlassFish 5.0 is certified to work with java sdk 8u144 as mentioned HERE: https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/release-notes.pdf.

Be aware, the path may also contain a reference to an old SDK directory.

If you need more help, please post the results of calling `echo %PATH%` on your `cmd`.

Comment: In path of Environmental Variables i have java 9 because i use that one as default, but in the glassfish project i have explicitly set java 8 since 9 is not yet supported by glassfish. I guess the if the problem is that it reads the java in path instead of in the project i will just stay with netbeans until glassfish will be compatible with java 9 or they will fix this. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

In my case JDK 1.8.0_152 must be installed, path and java_home variables have to be configured AND JDK 9.X must be uninstalled. Without uninstall, the error persist.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall **Java 9**, stay with the version **8 update 162 and the jdk8**. When you unistall the Java 9 your system variables (PATH, **JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath**) will update the 3 jar (**java, javaw, javaws**) in this path to **Java version  8**.

Answer (score 0):

***war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080***
....

Assuming that you are certain that JDK has set well in your environment variables and you are using jdk 8 or lower-Well I read somewhere that java9 has issues with such configurations, maybe the issue has been solve but for my case I chose to avoid for now.

1. Download and extract GlassFish of your version. For my case I'm
   using GlassFish 5.181.O on Intellij 2018.1 **ultimate version**
2. Start Intellij, and ***before*** opening any project, or rather close all projects that are open.

   3. Click on ***configure***, then ***settings***. A new window will appear as shown below. I have marked the steps you need to follow in the image. I will also add some explanation here.
   4. Under **Application Servers**, click on the **+** shown as step **2** on the image, here you need to specify you glassfish server, the folder where you extracted to.
   5. Next, click  on  **+** shown in step **3** on the image to add the server modules.
   6. Assuming all is a success upto this point, select all choices of as shown in step **4** on the image, apply changes and Ok.
   7. I will explain about creating a new project because I'm not sure how you would handle an existing project but I guess you can use concepts here to figure out what you need to tweak.***Create*** your new java ee or whatever application you are working on,
   8. As shown on figure 2, assuming you are creating a Java EE app, Click on **Java Enterprise**, then check/tick **Web Application** and **JSF**
   9. Under **libraries**, ***use library from Glassfish ... Installation*** didn't help much because I got null pointer exceptions., so I used **Download** as shown in figure 2. Click next and finish.
   10. Automatically you will see GlassFish added to the project, run it from the IDE.
       [image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit**
If you had done all of the above and still get some error like Null Pointer Exceptions. Do what @Jailson Evora says: Clear your systems from java 9 and install java 8 and make sure when you issue **`java -version`** on command line, the output is java 8

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall both jdk9 and jdk10 and set my java_home back to jdk8_181